# Default Constraints in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4

Very simple question that NO ONE has directly answered. Is there no way to insert an entity using EF4 that uses the database default constraint and yet allows that field to be updated later?  There doesn't seem to be. When I have a date property for instance and want it to use the database default, I seem to have two options:

1) Set the "StoreGeneratedPattern" to "Computed" or "Identity" which prevents me from updating it later.

2) Ignore the database default entirely and set the default value myself.

Neither one of these options will work for me, and this seems to be a huge weakness with the framework. Any ideas? Is this bug resolved in EF5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

[Relevant UserVoice suggestion](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2929682-support-database-default-values-in-code-first).

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is the same. I haven't found any model-first or database-first specific suggestion on the UserVoice site, but I suspect support for Code-First would mostly imply support for other scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the generated class and set the default values in the constructor of the patial class.

```
public partial MyEntityClass MyEntity
{
    public MyEntityClass() 
    {
        this.DefaultValueProperty = defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to set them in code. I want them to be set in the database where they belong.